# How to correct a function error, TypeError 'flattenArray' is not a function in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am learning basic testing in with Mocha and Chai. My test keeps failing with the error, "TypeError: flattenArray is not a function". Here is the function code...flattenArray.js

```
 export function flattenArray(arr){
 let result = [];
   arr.forEach(function(element) {
      if(!Array.isArray(element)) {
       result.push(element);
      } else {
        result = result.concat(flattenArrays(element));
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

and here is my test file, flattenArray.spec.js

```
var chai = require('chai');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var describe = require('mocha').describe;
import * as flattenArray from '../src/flattenArray';


describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#flattenArray()', function() {
    it('should return a single, flat array', function(){
      expect(flattenArray([1,2,3])).to.be.equal([1,2,3])
   })
  })
})



describe('Array', function() {
  it('should start empty', function() {
    var arr = [];
    assert.equal(arr.length, 0);
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I have one passing and one failing. How do I get the flattenArray test to work?

Comment: Your import looks wrong, shouldn't it be `import { flattenArray } from '../src/flattenArray';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `flattenArray()` is a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports). You should import it like this:

```
import { flattenArray } from '../src/flattenArray';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [1, 2, 'abc', [4 ,{a:[5],b:{c:6}}], [], [[7]], null, 8,['xyz',9],[[]]];
let newArray = [];
function flattenArray(arr){
  for(var i in arr){
    if(typeof arr[i] != "object"){
      newArray.push(arr[i])
    }else{
      flattenArray(arr[i])
    };
  }
  return newArray;
}
console.log(flattenArray(data));
```